# How can calling a function pointer saved from a previous execution fail?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I was curious if function pointers could be stored in a file and used at some future point in time when the program had exited and started again. For example, my first test program *looked* something like this pseudocode:

```
void f(){}

typedef void(*Fptr)();

int main() {
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    if (i == 1) {
        std::ofstream out(/**/);
        out << &f;
    }
    else {
        std::ifstream in(/**/);
        Fptr fp;
        in >> fp;
        fp();
    }
}
```

That is just the logic of what I wanted to do. I would launch it with input `1`, let it exit, and run it again with input `2`. Don't consider that to be my real code, as I erased the original test because...

**That only worked if I don't change the directory that the executable is in!**

Adding a new file to the directory (presumably removing a file too) and moving the executable somewhere new would all cause `fp();` to crash. The new function address would be a different value.

So I made a new test which calculates the difference between an old function pointer and a current function address. Applying that offset to an old function pointer and calling it yields the correct function call, regardless of what I do to the directory.

I am confident this is UB. However, like de-referencing a null pointer will cause a segfault, the UB is pretty consistent.

**Aside from rewriting the data with garbage, and assuming that the functions aren't loaded in a DLL, how likely is this method to succeed? In what ways will it still fail to work?**

Comment: Visual C++ will by default generate executable that scramble the load addresses. Relative addresses will generally work as long as they're within a module.

Comment: As you say it is undefined behavior. If you want to write safe, portable code, you can never rely on this.

Comment: It may work for a year and fail after an innocent OS update. Who knows. If you're adventurous, go ahead.

Comment: +1 for your curiosity. As already said using the relative address is going to work in most cases, as this is exactly what is done at a lower level when you call a function. (At least for position independent code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others mentioned, this problem is caused by the "Address Space Layout Randomization" (ASLR). This randomization is done for each module (i.e, each executable image). This means that if all your functions are contained in your .exe, they are guaranteed to to always have the same offset from the base of the module. If some function are in a DLL, the same apply, but from the base of the DLL module. It is important that the relative module addresses stay the same, because otherwise it wouldn't be possible to locate entry points and DLL functions.

On a Windows environment :

In Visual Studio (and MSVC), ASLR is ON by default, but you can disable it in the "Linker > Advanced > Randomized Base Address" option (/DYNAMICBASE:NO in command line). By disabling this option, the functions will always be at the same address.

You can also determine the offset at runtime. The module base address can be obtained with `GetModuleHandle()` (the module handle is in fact the base address). With this, you can work with relative addresses for your pointers.

```
uintptr_t base_address = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

uintptr_t offset = (uintptr_t)&f - base_address;
out << offset;

in >> offset;
fp = (Fptr)(offset + base_address);
fp();
```

Comment: Would it be theoretically possible for pieces of the module to be loaded into different pieces of non-consecutive memory? If functions had different offsets from the base as normal, that would be the quickest way for my hack to crash and burn. Or if function pointers were keys into some sort of lookup table, and therefore the values would have no relation to where the function is.

Comment: @JamesRoot Functions can be put in different sections, that can be loaded at different offsets, but if I'm not mistaken, the ASLR is done module-wise on Windows at least, so the offset can't change within a module.

Answer (score 1):

The function pointer will ONLY work if the program is loaded at the same address each time. Modern OS's have "address space randomization", which causes the actual address of code, data and stack to be moved around at random - to avoid stack overflow attacks that modify the return address - since it's not possible to know the address to "return to" if it is picked at random.

There are settings to disable the random changes.

Obviously, it also won't work if code is changed that is between the start of the code-section that the callee function in.

The pointer is converted to a `void *`, which should be possible - obviously, the file content won't work on another OS or processor architecture, but I don't see a particular reason for this not working.

However, a more portable way would be to store a sequence number of the operation you are using, rather than a function pointer. And then doing something like this:

```
for(;;)
  switch(sequence)
  {
    case 1:
      f();
      sequence++;
      break;

    case 2:
      g();
      sequence++;
      break;
   }
   ... 
}
```

On failure, store `sequence` (or `sequence - 1`).

The above assumes the `f` and `g` functions are throwing an exception or using `longjmp` to exit [or that `...` is checking for errors].

Beyond that, I can't see a technical reason why

Comment: However, if `&function1 - &function2` always yields the same offset, then adding `saved_pointer_address - &function1` to any old function pointer value would yield the current function's address, correct?

Comment: My suggestion, however, will work even if you recompile the code, adding some debug code or some such...